# Legal way US based Employer transfer money to India based employee

Tags: united-states, india, legal, legal-tender

I am a software engineer, currently working for a US based company.

Situation :

I have got my old US employer back with me where they want me to be their employee right now (meanwhile they are applying for my H1B visa, but it will take ~8 month to complete all process). my this employer is completely an US based legal company and no any existence in India.

Will it possible that they will credit my salary in my India bank account from US as normal process, If i work for them from here?

OR

is there any such bank account service, where its legal money transfer such to my account (As its Complete legal US company and No existence in India)?

I will be having all proof and legal signed employment letter with company. If above things possible than can you let me know, what are the documents you will need here?

legal way in both side (employer and employee)

Let me know, if you need for information. kindly response me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it possible that they will credit my salary in my India bank account from US as normal process, If i work for them from here?

There is no issue for an US based company to pay you a salary in India. You can get funds in your own savings account. You need to calculate and pay taxes on your own.